# Error in generated values-23 file in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error when I try to build my project.

```
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And when I click on it it takes me to the v-23 values file of generated folder  which contains following code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CardView" parent="Base.CardView">
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my app gradle file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.commit451:inkpageindicator:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

}
```

And when I change everything in gradle to version 23 this error goes away but as I am using http libraries and they are removed from 23 version therefore I am forced to use 22 version. My project was working perfectly fine before and at a sudden it started giving this error. Only thing I done was install a support repository which I was using in other project and it start giving error in this project too.
Any way to resolve this error?

Comment: Maybe you need to update `compileSdkVersion 22` and `targetSdkVersion 22` to version 23?

Comment: Also, yes `HttpClient` was removed and it is encouraged that you use `HttpURLConnection` instead.

Comment: I know but this is an old project that I am working on and I can't change complete flow now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'`
 needs **V-23**

In my case I use v-22 so 
i changed Facebook sdk version to 4.8
 `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'`

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you. I am using the Facebook SDK too and had this issue. ++1

Comment: This is the real deal

Comment: adding `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'` produces this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1`

Answer (score 6):

That error makes perfect sense, seeing as `?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating`
was only [added in API 23](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.R.attr.html) and you are using `compileSdkVersion 22`.

So, to fix the error, you need `compileSdkVersion 23` to include that resource in your build. Also, having a `v23` values file doesn't make sense when you have `targetSdkVersion 22`, which says you aren't targeting `v23` devices anyways.

And you mentioned the "http libraries" you are using are gone? If you are referring to `HttpClient` from the `org.apache` package, then you can add it back by including this in your `build.grade`

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to upgrade your modules,in addition solution is excluding modules in build.gradle with **compile** tag

```
compile( 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0')
   {
        exclude module: 'cardview-v7'
   }
```